# Specify custom temporary directory for ghc compiler

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am using ghc on my web server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Due to some restrictions, I cannot provide write permissions to /tmp folder.

The ghc compiler is throwing this error after removing permissions to the /tmp folder

```
/tmp/ghc12032_0: createDirectory: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

Is there a way to provide a custom temporary directory for ghc? I didn't find any compiler flag which can help with that. I need to provide a custom directory every time I invoke ghc. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/separate_compilation.html#redirecting-temporary-files

> `-tmpdir`
>
> If you have trouble because of running out of space in /tmp (or wherever your installation thinks temporary files should go), you may use the -tmpdir  option to specify an alternate directory. For example, -tmpdir . says to put temporary files in the current working directory.
>
> Alternatively, use your TMPDIR environment variable. Set it to the name of the directory where temporary files should be put. GCC and other programs will honour the TMPDIR variable as well.
>
> Even better idea: Set the DEFAULT_TMPDIR make variable when building GHC, and never worry about TMPDIR again. (see the build documentation).